# Google Sheets: how to find number of consecutive missed meetings

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to track the number of consecutive meetings that a person has missed.

I've got one column with names and a second column with the last meeting they attended. I've then got a separate column with an ordered list of meeting dates (they're not regular).

I want a formula that checks the last meeting attended against the list of meeting dates, and outputs the number of meetings that have occurred since.

I've no idea how to approach this. Can anyone offer a formula - or even a place to start?

Comment: Can you please attach an example sheet?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it!

The full formula is a bit of a muddled mess, but it does four things:

- finds total number of meetings (using COUNTA)
- finds the location of the last meeting in the list of meetings (using MATCH)
- uses the previous two values to find the range containing all the missed meetings (using CONCATENATE)
- counts the number of meetings in this range (using COUNTA)